# RewriteRules redirect specific domain https to http, opposite for the others

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that with a domain example.info. Recently I acquired two new domains: example.com and example.org.

I had a SSL certificate on example.info, and I was redirecting all http to https like this:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Now I want example.com to be the main url and the other two I just want to redirect to example.com.

I changed the SSL certificate from the .info to the .com and everything is good but my problem is that for example Google links me from the https://example.info and now it is failing because that url doesn't have the SSL certificate anymore. So what I want to do is to redirect https://example.info to https://example.com.

I have tried different things, but this is one of the solutions that didn't work.

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(www\.)?example\.info$
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.info$
  RewriteRule ^ https://example\.com [L,R=301]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve to redirect https://example.info to https://example.com and keep the redirection to https for example.com?

//// EDIT

If I can't redirect https://example.info because I don't have a valid certificate anymore, how do I prevent that when I write http://example.info it gets redirected to https?

Comment: You can't redirect `https://example.info` if it doesn't have a valid ssl cert.

Comment: Thanks. Then is there any solution for when you don't want to have a certificate anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.(info|org)$
RewriteRule ^ https://example\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I ended up doing something like this, because else for some reason it would still try to redirect to https://example.info, but I accept your answer because it put me on the right track.

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.info$
RewriteRule ^ https://example\.com/$1 [R=301,L]